# What could prevent webview's content being cached?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm seeing my webview loads all resources/assets (js, css) every time it's loaded, I was wondering what could prevent these contents being cached and thus not able to be reused?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a matter of the server cache policy and has nothing to do with the WebView.

BTW, Are you sure they are re-loaded, or just polled for changes and not actually re-fetched?

Try to debug this using Chrome on your PC.